# Is there a way to use GraphQL to display a filtered list?

Tags: graphql

So, I have a GraphQL request where I am pulling every film from every studio in my api. I'm wondering if I can pull a filtered list of only films that have a specific cast or crew member with GraphQL, or if I'd have to do this with server code:

```
  allStudios {
    
    films{
      title
      logline
      characters{
        characterName
        characterDescription
      }
      crew{
        role
        member{
          id
          firstName 
          lastName
        }
        
      }
      videoFile{
        video{
          thumbnailUrl
          mp4Url
        }
      }
      studio{
        id
      }
    }
```

ex: I would only pull a film from the api if it had Ryan Reynolds as a cast or crew member.

Comment: Have you tried filter?

Comment: Yes, but filter only takes me so far. I'm trying to filter the top-level element by a field in a low-level element which is where I'm having issues.

Comment: I recommend creating a GraphQL query that does the required database query (ex: JOIN) to find by actor. E.g.: `studiosByCrewMember(firstName: String!, lastName: String!) {…}`